# Selenium Python - Unable to close modal popup window - DOM not traversable

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, dom

Edit - Is there any way to click outside of a modal window if there is an iframe present?  I think that could be a solution.  Is there a way to click on any point of a browser window without having to target a specific element while doing it?  I noticed that if you click outside of the modal box, the modal disappears.

I am working on backtesting a modal popup window and I am having issues with selecting and closing the modal popup window.

It seems the DOM is not traversable (when you select the button with chrome inspector and try to trigger an action, any action I try to trigger doesn't seem to work because the element is null, however it is present and I am able to select it).

See iframe here -
[https://servedby.flashtalking.com/container/18442;121244;12954;iframe/?ftXRef=[%INSERT_TRANSACTION_ID_HERE%]&ftXValue=[%INSERT_TRANSACTION_VALUE_HERE%]&ftXType=[%INSERT_TRANSACTION_TYPE_HERE%]&ftXName=[%INSERT_TRANSACTION_NAME_HERE%]&ftXNumItems=[%INSERT_TRANSACTION_QUANTITY_HERE%]&ftXCurrency=[%INSERT_TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_HERE%]&U1=[%INSERT_U1_HERE%]&U2=[%INSERT_U2_HERE%]&U3=[%INSERT_U3_HERE%]&U4=[%INSERT_U4_HERE%]&U5=[%INSERT_U5_HERE%]&U6=[%INSERT_U6_HERE%]&U7=[%INSERT_U7_HERE%]&U8=[%INSERT_U8_HERE%]&U9=[%INSERT_U9_HERE%]&U10=[%INSERT_U10_HERE%]&U11=[%INSERT_U11_HERE%]&U12=[%INSERT_U12_HERE%]&U13=[%INSERT_U13_HERE%]&U14=[%INSERT_U14_HERE%]&U15=[%INSERT_U15_HERE%]&U16=[%INSERT_U16_HERE%]&U17=[%INSERT_U17_HERE%]&U18=[%INSERT_U18_HERE%]&U19=[%INSERT_U19_HERE%]&U20=[%INSERT_U20_HERE%]&ft_referrer=https%3A//www.upwork.com/ab/find-work/domestic&ns=https%3A//www.upwork.com/ab/account-security/login&cb=121066.74962680253](https://servedby.flashtalking.com/container/18442;121244;12954;iframe/?ftXRef=%5B%INSERT_TRANSACTION_ID_HERE%%5D&ftXValue=%5B%INSERT_TRANSACTION_VALUE_HERE%%5D&ftXType=%5B%INSERT_TRANSACTION_TYPE_HERE%%5D&ftXName=%5B%INSERT_TRANSACTION_NAME_HERE%%5D&ftXNumItems=%5B%INSERT_TRANSACTION_QUANTITY_HERE%%5D&ftXCurrency=%5B%INSERT_TRANSACTION_CURRENCY_HERE%%5D&U1=%5B%INSERT_U1_HERE%%5D&U2=%5B%INSERT_U2_HERE%%5D&U3=%5B%INSERT_U3_HERE%%5D&U4=%5B%INSERT_U4_HERE%%5D&U5=%5B%INSERT_U5_HERE%%5D&U6=%5B%INSERT_U6_HERE%%5D&U7=%5B%INSERT_U7_HERE%%5D&U8=%5B%INSERT_U8_HERE%%5D&U9=%5B%INSERT_U9_HERE%%5D&U10=%5B%INSERT_U10_HERE%%5D&U11=%5B%INSERT_U11_HERE%%5D&U12=%5B%INSERT_U12_HERE%%5D&U13=%5B%INSERT_U13_HERE%%5D&U14=%5B%INSERT_U14_HERE%%5D&U15=%5B%INSERT_U15_HERE%%5D&U16=%5B%INSERT_U16_HERE%%5D&U17=%5B%INSERT_U17_HERE%%5D&U18=%5B%INSERT_U18_HERE%%5D&U19=%5B%INSERT_U19_HERE%%5D&U20=%5B%INSERT_U20_HERE%%5D&ft_referrer=https%3A//www.upwork.com/ab/find-work/domestic&ns=https%3A//www.upwork.com/ab/account-security/login&cb=121066.74962680253)

In chrome inspector, you see the following [Image of inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X48wQ.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is how the modal is structured:
div.modal-static
up-c-transition
div.modal-backdrop
div.modal
div.modal-dialog
div.modal-content
div.modal-header
up-c-header
div.header-wrapper
div
slot
button
up-c-icon
span.sr-only
sr-only
up-c-load-svg
svg

[Code in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTsx3.png)

I'm not sure how to get the name of the iframe I should switch to, this is my biggest issue.  I believe maybe if I can switch to the iframe I can potentially interact with the modal buttons.

Edit - Here is the full code that is produced - https://codeshare.io/2WxdLE

Comment: Long link leads to empty page

Comment: Here is the full code that is produced - https://codeshare.io/2WxdLE

Comment: What do you do to open the modal? Page continuously reloads if I open it locally

Comment: So it’s a modal that pops up after a user logs in, it seems to load within the first few seconds of logging in.  I’m not sure if I can replicate it without an actual account because I believe there is another website that is generating the pop up (or iFrame).  Basically what happens is any modal element is null inside the modal container when trying to traverse the DOM.  Let me know if a video would help, getting it to load for you would be much better but I will see what I can come up with.

Comment: Here is something that might help - https://confection.io/scripts/servedby-flashtalking-com-container-4790-108288-11134-iframe/